# Why is $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin(2x)} = \frac{6}{2}=3$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin(2x)} = \frac{6}{2}=3$?

The justification is that $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$

But, I am not seeing the connection.
L'Hospital's rule? Is there a double angle substitution happening?

Comment: I would like to point out that the use of L'Hopital's rule to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is circular, since it requires the knowledge of the derivative of $\sin(x)$ at zero, which is what $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is in the first place. Therefore, either accept and use the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$ or prove it in some other fashion. There are many geometric and analytic proofs of the limit out there, but likely it is expected for you to memorize the limit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin(6x)}{{\sin(2x)}} =\frac{\sin(6x)}{6x} \cdot \frac{2x}{{\sin(2x)} }\cdot \frac{6}{2} $$

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to know any special limits or derivatives, you can do it with trig identities:

From

$$\sin3\theta=\sin(\theta+2\theta)=\sin\theta\cos2\theta+\cos\theta\sin2\theta=\sin\theta\cos2\theta+2\sin\theta\cos^2\theta$$

we have, letting $\theta=2x$,

$${\sin6x\over\sin2x}={\sin2x(\cos4x+2\cos^22x)\over\sin2x}=\cos4x+2\cos^22x$$

and thus

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\sin6x\over\sin2x}=\lim_{x\to0}(\cos4x+2\cos^22x)=\cos0+2\cos^20=1+2=3$$

(The final evaluation relies, of course, on knowing that the cosine function is continuous.)

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing it like this. Innovative !

Answer (score 5):

As user Daniel has written you can express the ratio $\frac{\sin 6x}{\sin 2x}$ in a way which makes it amenable to the use of standard limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1\ .$$ Notice that $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{2x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin 6x}{6x}\ .$$ As long as the argument $x$ is not equal to zero (and $\sin 2x \neq 0$) you can prolong the ratio $\frac{\sin 6x}{\sin 2x}$ as follows.

$$\frac{\sin 6x}{\sin 2x} = \frac{\sin 6x}{6x} \cdot \frac{6x}{2x} \cdot \frac{2x}{\sin 2x} = \underbrace{\frac{\sin 6x}{6x}}_{\to 1} \cdot \frac{6}{2} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}}}_{\to\frac{1}{1}} \to 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 1 = 3 \ .$$ Hence you obtain the result $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin 6x}{\sin 2x} = 3 \ .$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin(2x)}$$ $$= \lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{6}{2} \cdot \frac{\frac{\sin(6x)}{6x}}{\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}}$$ $$=\frac{6}{2}$$ $$=3$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: rewrite the quotient in the form $$\frac{\sin(6x)}{6x}\frac{1}{\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}}\cdot 3$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the limit of both the numerator and denominator are 0 use L'Hopitals rule. You then get $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{6cos(6x)}{2cos(2x)}=\frac{6}{2}=3$

Comment: "Since the limit of both the numerator and denominator are 0 use L'Hopitals rule" No thanks, see comment on main.

Comment: Good call. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use [Hopital rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):
$$\begin{align}
\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} &= \lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{\sin'(x)}{1}\\
&= \lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)}{1}\\
&= \lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1}\\
&=1
\end{align}
$$
hence
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin(2x)} &= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin(2x)} \cdot \frac{2x}{6x} \cdot \frac{6}{2}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(6x)}{6x} \cdot \frac{\sin(2x)}{6x} \cdot 3\\
&= 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 3\\
&=3
\end{align}$$

Comment: "The key is to use Hopital rule" Well, no, see comment on main.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x}{\sin2x}\cdot\frac{\sin6x}{6x}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

In asymptotic terms, $\displaystyle \lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$ means that "$\sin(x)$ behaves like $x$ around $0$".

To this understanding, $\sin(6x)$ behaves like $6x$ and $\sin(2x)$ behaves like $2x$ around $0$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin(2x)}$ behaves like $\displaystyle \frac{6x}{2x}=3$ around $0$.

In other words,  $\displaystyle \lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin(2x)} = 3.$

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange.27s_trigonometric_identities) we find

$$1+2\cos u + 2 \cos 2 u + 2 \cos 3 u + ... + 2 \cos n u=\frac{\sin \frac{2n+1}{2}u}{\sin\frac u2}$$

In the left hand side set $u=4x$ and $n=1$ so that the left hand side becomes $$\frac{\sin 6x}{\sin 2x},$$ therefore we have $$1+2\cos 4x = \frac{\sin 6x}{\sin 2x}$$